# Prepared statement not running MYSQLI PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have been attempting to switch over to prepared statements, however I cant figure out why my new code no longer functions. I am new to using these and still learning but i understand it is the best practice for security. any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

```
<?php
$servername = "11.11.11.11";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "sit";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);


if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `ourstory` ");
$values = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


if(isset($_POST['ourstory_title'])){
$ourstory_title = $_POST['ourstory_title'];
$ourstory_testimonial = $_POST['ourstory_testimonial'];
$ourstory_content = $_POST['ourstory_content'];
$ourstory->execute();

$ourstory = $conn->prepare("UPDATE ourstory SET
    ourstory_title='$ourstory_title' ,
    ourstory_content='$ourstory_content' ,
    ourstory_testimonial='$ourstory_testimonial' 
    WHERE  ourstory_id='1'");
$ourstory->bind_param("sss", $ourstory_title, $ourstory_content, $ourstory_testimonial);   




if (mysqli_query($conn, $ourstory)) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}   
$ourstory->close();
$conn->close();

}

?>
<form id="comment_form" method="post" 
      action="<?php echo $ourstory?>" 
      onsubmit="setTimeout(function () { 
             window.location.reload(); 
      }, 10), location.reload(true);">

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">


<tr>
<td width="85%">About Us Title</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
   <input class="commentarea" 
          name="ourstory_title" type="text" 
          id="ourstory_title" value="<?php echo $values['ourstory_title']?>">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="85%" >Testimonial</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
   <pre>
     <textarea class="commentarea" 
      name="ourstory_testimonial" type="text" 
      id="ourstory_testimonial" rows= "10" ><?php echo $values['ourstory_testimonial']?>
     </textarea>
   </pre>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="85%" >About Us Content</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
  <pre>
    <textarea class="commentarea" name="ourstory_content" 
        type="text" id="ourstory_content"  
         rows= "10" ><?php echo $values['ourstory_content']?>
    </textarea>
  </pre>
 </td>
</tr>


<tr>

<td>

<input type="submit" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81295/discussion-between-fred-ii-and-sean-devine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In conjunction with Mark's answer, am submitting the following as a complimentary answer and using some of my comments left under the OP's question.

Firstly, `<textarea>` does not have a type. `type="text"` remove all of those.

Then, `$ourstory->execute();` is misplaced, it needs to go after `$ourstory->bind_param("sss",...` once you've used Mark's answer and using placeholders as stated in the answer and from the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

You shouldn't have `if (mysqli_query($conn, $ourstory)) {` what you're looking to use is `affected_rows` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php in a conditional statement to check if the query was indeed successful.

---

From your edit: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31003865/4

```
printf("Affected rows (UPDATE): %d\n", $ourstory->affected_rows);
$ourstory->execute();
```

this needs to go after executing:

```
$ourstory->execute();
printf("Affected rows (UPDATE): %d\n", $ourstory->affected_rows);
```

but I would use a conditional `if` for that **and it should be the connection's variable**, i.e. and from the manual:

```
int $mysqli->affected_rows;
```

so do:

```
printf("Affected rows (UPDATE): %d\n", $conn->affected_rows);
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Example from the manual:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* Insert rows */
$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE Language SELECT * from CountryLanguage");
printf("Affected rows (INSERT): %d\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ourstory = $conn->prepare("UPDATE ourstory SET ourstory_title='$ourstory_title' ,ourstory_content='$ourstory_content' ,ourstory_testimonial='$ourstory_testimonial' WHERE  ourstory_id='1'");
$ourstory->bind_param("sss", $ourstory_title, $ourstory_content, $ourstory_testimonial);
```

If you're binding values to your prepared statement, you need to set placeholders in that query.... not inject the values themselves and then try binding them

```
$ourstory = $conn->prepare("UPDATE ourstory SET ourstory_title=? ,ourstory_content=? ,ourstory_testimonial=? WHERE  ourstory_id='1'");
$ourstory->bind_param("sss", $ourstory_title, $ourstory_content, $ourstory_testimonial);
```

And you might as well bind the value for `ourstory_id` as well

Comment: [See my comment to the OP Mark...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003865/prepared-statement-not-running-mysqli-php#comment50035514_31003865) and the one under it too.

Comment: I guess I covered all or most of it in comments. Yet, if they happen to disappear, then...